# Get Pointer Value

Tags: c++, pointers

I am new to c++ pointers, and I have an issue with getting a value from a pointer.

I have a pointer, verticesPosBegin , which points to the beginning of an array used to hold vertex positions. Each vertex is stored as a 3 component float vector (xyz).

I need to obtain each vertex from it and to access its x,y,z values.

I did it the following way:

```
NxVec3* positions = (NxVec3*)data.verticesPosBegin;

for(int i=0;i<nrVertices;i++)
{

  NxVec3* p1 = (NxVec3*)positions;
  printf("Vertex coordinates x: %d, y: %d, z: %d\n", p1->x, p1->y, p1->z);
  positions++;
}
```

(NxVec3 is juat a type defined by a physics engine that I use, it is basically a structure of the form (float x, float y, float z))

But this does not get me the values of the coordinates, but the addresses, I guess, since they represent very large numbers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the casts are necessary? And what are the types of `p1->[x, y, z]`?

Comment: Also, this is c++ people, learn to use `std::cout`. Had to be said ;)

Comment: @0x499602D2: According to the sentence after the code, they are floats.

Comment: why you need two times type casting?

Comment: If I understand it right, `NxVec3::get()` returns the array of coordinates.

Comment: First replace the `%d`'s in your format string with `%f`. Or cast your floats to `int` in the parameter list. Second, ensure your `data.verticesPosBegin` is **valid**. If it is an invalid pointer value (and that cast is useless if it *is* valid) then the rest of your output will be undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your statement, `p1->x`, `p1->y` and `p1->z` are of type `float`, correct?  If so, you are passing an incorrect format string to printf.  The `%d` flag is for integers.  You probably want the `%f` flag instead.  The huge numbers you are getting are not addresses, but rather float values, converted to a doubles, then their bit patterns interpreted as integers, though it is technically undefined behavior.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

If you use cout instead, you don't have to worry about things like this, because it is type safe.

P.S.

Stop casting. It will only hide compile-time, and shift them to run-time errors, which is significantly worse.

Answer (score 1):

- If you really want to use pointer (i'd recommend that only for practise purposes) and
- if `data.verticesPosBegin` points to a contiguous block of Nx3 floats
- and if NxVec3 is class/struct with only three data members  `float x, y, z;`

the following should work:

```
NxVec3 *positions = (NxVec3*)data.verticesPosBegin, *p(positions);

for(unsigned int i=0;i<nrVertices;i++)
{
  cout << "Vertex coordinates ";
  cout << "x: " << p->x << ", ";
  cout << "y: " << p->y << ", ";
  cout << "z: " << p->z << endl;
  ++p;
}
```

Comment: The assessment if the first three floats being all that is printed is wrong. `p1` is set to the value of the just-incremented `positions` pointer, which never resets while in the loop, and only  increments on each iteration. The opening statement, therefore, in this answer, is *wrong* (though the code will work, but only because it implicitly sidesteps the real issue: using `%d` to print an uncast `float`).

Comment: Sloppy reading by me - Upvote for you. I'll edit this. (Eventhough I wouldn't call it sidestepping. Replacing the wrong output by a correct version is a correct solution. Regardless of using corrected printf() or cout instead.)

Answer (score 0):

If I get the `NxVec3` right, here is the definition, [NxVec3](https://shooter-zhouqi.googlecode.com/svn-history/r68/trunk/SDK/PhysX/Foundation/include/NxVec3.h), so, according to the header file, the following should work:

```
NxVec3* positions = (NxVec3*)data.verticesPosBegin;

for(int i = 0;i < nrVertices; ++i)
{
    float *p = positions[i].get();
    cout << p[0] << ' ' << p[1] << ' ' << p[2] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The problem was indeed the type in the printf function.